# A noun with more than one adjective

Tags: grammar

May I ask if a noun is modified by more than one adjective that indicates two kinds of thing, whether we should use a plural or singular noun? For example, we should say "Japanese and Western cultures" or "Japanese and Western culture"?

Comment: How many (distinct) cultures are you talking about?

Comment: Two distinct cultures. I got it, thanks Hot Licks!

Answer (score 5):

"X and Y culture" would be a culture shared by X and Y. "X and Y cultures" would be two cultures, one for X and one for Y. I presume you mean the latter in your example.